# Text overlay over imageview in android

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, textview

I am trying to have textviews overlay over imageviews. Something like this

[image: people app]

Can someone help me with the code.

Comment: Do you have the gridview set up?

Comment: No but I think I can manage that

Comment: Then you could create a custom xml with frameLayout or relativeLayout and position a textview over an imageview and inflate it in your gridview adapter

Comment: @kabuto178 is right. A custom gridview will make it easier

Comment: I am not able to manage the spacing between the two cards. I too need the images/cards close to each other as shown in the above pic in the question. But I am seeing some horizontal & vertical gaps. Tried all stretchMode combinations. Any quick fix ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it using a custom gridView. You must apply this in getView.

Custom gridView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_practitioner" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/item_image" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionContent"
    />  

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#CC515116"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView             
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/text_enter_pass_password"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
             />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_practitioner_pin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
                android:ems="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" 
            />              

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/pract_button"
                 android:layout_width="70dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/buton_shape"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                 android:text="@string/btn_ok" 
             />
    </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#bbffffff"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

     <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginTop="3dp" 
         android:textColor="@color/text_black"    
         android:gravity="bottom|center"
         android:textSize="20sp" 
         android:textAllCaps="true"
         android:paddingBottom="0dp"
      />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text_pratiotioner_group_name"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:textColor="@color/sub_title_color"   
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:gravity="bottom|center"
         android:textAllCaps="true"
     />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrap a TextView and ImageView into FrameLayout, put the TextView in FrameLayout after ImageView. Then, wrap the FrameLayout into RelativeLayout OR LinearLayout. Make some position setup (as per the needs).

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
        <ImageView />
        <TextView />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a frame layout and within the frame layout keep an imageview and a linearlayout(with a translucent background and a textview).

The translucent color can be placed in the colors file as :     #80000000  
Here is a snippet :)

```
 <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFullScreenAd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_page_ad" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/translucent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Please swipe up"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Though an old question but should incase anyone is interested in the card view version of this question here you go...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:clickable="true">

     <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#89969F">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_overlay"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="196dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:background="#80000000"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:textSize="22sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:text="Settings"
                 android:textColor="@color/white"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:padding="8dp" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: thanx :) But I am not able to manage the spacing between the two cards. I too need the images/cards close to each other as shown in the pic in the question. But I am seeing some horizontal & vertical gaps. Tried all stretchMode combinations. Any quick fix ?

Comment: if i get you right! you don't want the space between the cards. if YES then replace the 'android.support.v7.widget.CardView' with 'RelativeLayout''. that should remove the borders you see. Ther are caused by card view 'cardElevation' attribute.

Comment: ok.. but I need to use cards. I will try removing the cardElevation attribute & update. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the layout accordingly, If you want to accommodate the images on an imageview only, then you can drop the below layout in a relative one including an imageview too.

```
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/your_image"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        <!-- layout_gravity="supply accordingly" -->
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```