# How to show text over image?

Tags: android, uiimageview, textview

I have to show two line text as attached image .

[image]

In this image I have to show text "Hotel Seawoods, Mahalaxmi
20% Cashback" over image .

Please tell me how to do this ?

activity_home.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Neeraj" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shah"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#"
        android:textSize="50dp" />


</FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_1_background"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_eye"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Explore"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/location"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Location"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/deals"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Deals"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/cuisine"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Cusine"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/drive"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Drive-in"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_1_background"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/recent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Recents"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note : In this xml `"test_image"`(test) is image, where i have to show text.

i am getting now after changes while i was getting earlier cardview 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text overlay over imageview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877170/text-overlay-over-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your ImageView in a RelativeLayout & align the textviews to bottom left like below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hotel Seawoods, Mahalaxmi"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20% Cashback"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a frame layout

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/lake"
        android:scaleType="matrix"></ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="@string/top_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bottom_text"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

for more information see
[this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-frame-layouts--mobile-4877).

Comment: After using this my card view is not appearing i am editing  my code and snapshot what i am getting now. My card view disappeared like all icons view after use of this.

Answer (score 0):

use layout in this format as below

```
  <RelativeLayout>
   <FrameLayout>
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
   </FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout. Try This:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this mentioned in most other places, but be careful with usage of RelativeLayout. The top level view has to be declared below the low level view. Otherwise, it'll be wrongly overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

i am adding constraintlayout inside cardview and manage the position (margin) and it will be like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/kmp_warna1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                android:text="Kampung Warna"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Gang 1, Jodipan, Kesatrian, Blimbing"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it will help